# Move CALAyer position to be entirely encapsulated by super CALayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, calayer, cgrect

I have two CALayers, one which is to be dragged into the other.  If the dragged CALAyer is not completely within destination CALayer, i want to move it so that it is (not to a set point, just to the closed possible point that will mean the layer is fully within the destination layer).  I'm really not sure if there is a simple way to achieve this?

I am checking with the following,

```
if (!CGRectContainsRect(destinationLayer.frame, draggedLayer.frame)) {

                NSLog(@"Not completely with container");
            }
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

- First of all, you should make sure the moved layer must be smaller than the outer one.
- Then you can just make the min x equal to the min x of the outer one if it's on the left or max x to max x if it's on the other side.
- The same way to the y-axis.

//The x-aixs code is like below, the y-axis is similar

```
if in.frame.origin.x < out.frame.origin.x {
    in.frame.origin = out.frame.origin.x //In objective-c you cannot set it directly like this, it only works in swift!!!!
} else if in.frame.origin.x > out.frame.origin.x {
    in.frame.origin = out.frame.origin.x
}
```

I think it's the easiest way. Also you should attention to transform as the frame is a computed property which is the bounding box of the layer, so the procedure won't differ to the one above.

Comment: thanks for the response, how would i set the min x position? Example would be very helpful

Comment: I add more details, if you use objective-c, please attention to the set frame code as you do before, the swift code won't work in objective-c.